# selenium webdriver inside soapui, passing the driver instance

Tags: selenium, groovy, selenium-webdriver, soapui

I am currently working on a testsuite that is maintained inside soapui. This testsuite also contains some web functionality tests that are implemented as `HTTP.GET` and `HTTP.POST` requests. I would like to port those tests to WebDriver. Inside SoapUI, there is a possibility to run a groovy script that basically gives you access to writing java code which I have been trying to do.

What I have at the moment is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;


LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
loginPage.login()

public class LoginPage {

    WebDriver driver = null;

    public WebDriver initDriver(){
        if (driver == null ){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://mysite")}
    }

//  @FindBy(id = "j_username") WebElement userName;
//  @FindBy(id = "j_password") WebElement password;
//  @FindBy(xpath = "//h2[contains(text(), \"kasutajanime\")]//..//..//input[@class=\"button\"]") WebElement btnSubmit
    public LoginPage(){

        driver = initDriver()
    //  PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }


    public void login(){
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("j_username"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("j_password"));
        WebElement btnSubmit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(), \"kasutajanime\")]//..//..//input[@class=\"button\"]"));
        userName.sendKeys("SOAPUI")
        password.sendKeys("soapui")
        btnSubmit.click()       
}
}
```

When I run it, I get:

> Fri Mar 07 13:09:44 EET 2014:ERROR:java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Cannot invoke method findElement() on null object
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method findElement() on
>   null object
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>         at LoginPage.login(Script52.groovy:34)
>         at LoginPage$login.call(Unknown Source)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>         at Script52.run(Script52.groovy:9)
>         at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:96)
>         at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149)
>         at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Anyway, even if I do:

```
public void login(){
        driver = initDriver()
```

Which shouldn't open new instance as I am checking if the driver exists or not, it still opens an new instance.

I have been trying to declare the driver instance as static, but with no luck.

If not writing a class but simply calling WebDriver routines, everything works. Has anybody ever tried something like that? Is it even possible or am I missing something obvious (soapUI does not offer too many debugging options)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41280226/363573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you shouldn't initialize your driver as `WebDriver driver = null;` It should be just `WebDriver driver;`
In addition you write

```
public WebDriver initDriver(){
            if (driver == null ){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://mysite")}
        }
```

But if you want to have single browser you should have

```
public WebDriver initDriver(){
if (driver == null) {
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }
  return driver;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work. I really don't think that there is a difference, is there?

Comment: arrrrgh, so stupid. so obvious. The thing is that soapui does not offer any debug/autocomplete/compile warnings so I just missed it.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you set `driver` to be:

```
    driver = initDriver()
```

Then in `initDriver()`, you set driver up if it's null

```
    if (driver == null ){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver()
        driver.get("http://mysite")
    }
```

But then don't return anything if it isn't `null`

This then sets `driver` to `null` in the constructor.

Try changing:

```
    driver = initDriver()
```

to

```
    initDriver()
```

in the constructor

Comment: Thanks for this, i am accepting the other answer because it was here before.