# Import class automatically into every groovy script for a SoapUI project

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a SoapUI project, and an external custom Java library of utility methods that I've written for using in Groovy scripts.

In the Java library, I have a particular utility class, `com.custom.acmeproject.ContextProperties`, that has utility methods for changing the values of properties in the context of groovy scripts.  Using this class, I can do the following in a groovy script file:

```
import com.custom.acmeproject.ContextProperties;

ContextProperties.increment(context, "messageId");
```

- However, I'd like to be able to write that script *without* the
  import statement.  Is there a way I can setup my SoapUI project to
  *automatically* import this class into all of my Groovy scripts?

  I would prefer to be able to do this just for this one SoapUI
  project, without affecting other SoapUI projects; however, if this is
  not possible, I'll take a solution that will affect all my projects.
- Because this SoapUI project is automated using a maven build run in
  Jenkins, I need this solution to work both for running the tests in
  the SoapUI IDE (I'm using SoapUI NG Pro), and for running the tests
  using the `soapui-pro-maven-plugin`.
- Preferably, any solution should also work *without* having to
  manually configure Groovy settings outside of SoapUI across multiple 
  environments.

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2011/06/groovy-goodness-add-imports.html You *might* be able to do that as part of the Project setup script.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41280226/363573

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you completely aware that how an external library is written, compile, build jar file and placed under `SoapUI Pro` and same is the procedure for  `SoapUI Open Source` edition too.

I also understand that you also know how to code it in `java`, and aware of `package` for organizing the `class` files better, as well as that also convey by whom (individual or an organization) the library was created, and standard practice. But that can be optional.

> However, I'd like to be able to write that script without the import statement. Is there a way I can setup my SoapUI project to automatically import this class into all of my Groovy scripts?

So as you mentioned in the question, in order to avoid `import` in the `Groovy Scripts`, use one of the blow:

1. do not use any `package` for the library classes, and recompile, build jar and place under *soapUI*, and restart to take effect. Then you should be able to call `ContextProperties.increment(context, "messageId")`
2. use fully qualified class which does not need an explicit `import` like `com.custom.acmeproject.ContextProperties.increment(context, "messageId")`

> I would prefer to be able to do this just for this one SoapUI project, without affecting other SoapUI projects; however, if this is not possible, I'll take a solution that will affect all my projects.

The libraries are loaded into `SoapUI`, and that is not specific / limited to a project and is applicable for all the project. But I am sure, there will not effect unless those are used in multiple project and not changing as per the updates. Otherwise, it should be ok.

> Because this SoapUI project is automated using a maven build run in
>   Jenkins, I need this solution to work both for running the tests in
>   the SoapUI IDE (I'm using SoapUI NG Pro), and for running the tests
>   using the `soapui-pro-maven-plugin`.

Yes, if you place the library files under required location, it works the same way. Have you tried and found any issue in doing so?

> Preferably, any solution should also work without having to
>   manually configure Groovy settings outside of SoapUI across multiple environments.

What changes do you feel to `configure Groovy settings`? There isn't any thing like that. If you find so, just update it. If the **SoapUI project** is running smooth in the tool which has `Groovy` scripts, then the same should be running smoothly from all the **channels** i.e., **running command line, using ant, maven, jenkins** etc.

Does it sound good?