# groovy jar file in sopaui project

Tags: groovy, soapui

i am involving different project (Web services) automation and repeating same code like (reading response, validating errors codes, capturing response, reading Test from Excel sheet. how can i do all this code in jar file (using Eclipse GUI with Groovy) build the jar file and import in soapui.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742995/how-to-define-a-global-class-in-soapui-as-a-groovy-script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687528/creating-groovy-jar-file-and-call-in-soapui-free-version - a duplicate?

Comment: Where is the difficulty for you? and what you have tried?